# Neural Network: Why can't I overfit?

Tags: r, neural-networks, overfitting, caret

I have a (feed-forward single layer) neural network with which I try to predict an environment-related variable from two financial variables (regression). I use the "train" function from the caret package.

I use the `nnet()` algorithm in the caret package. I have two continuous predictors, and 420 data points.

For theoretical understanding, I try to purposely overfit my model; to my understanding, this should normally work with *every* dataset, e.g. bei increasing the "size" (i.e. the number of hidden units). However, increasing the size of hidden units drastically does not lead to overfitting.

Thus, is it wrong to assume that you can overfit every neural network by increasing "size"? Which other variable could lead to an overfitting instead?

```
grid <- expand.grid(size = 20
                    )

control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                        number = 10,
                        verboseIter = TRUE
                        )

fit <- train(x=train_parametres, y=train_result, 
             method = "mlp", 
             metric = "Rsquared",
             learnFunc = "Std_Backpropagation",
             learnFuncParams = c(0.2, 0.0),
             maxit = 1000,
             trControl = control,
             tuneGrid = grid,
             preProcess = c("center", "scale"), 
             linout = T,
             verbose = T,
             allowParallel = T
)
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason to try to overfit a data set is in order to understand the model capacity needed in order to represent your dataset.

If our model capacity is too low, you won't be able to represent your data set. When you increase the model capacity until you can fully represent your data set, you know you found the minimal capacity.

The overfitting is not the goal here, it is a by product. Your model probably represent the **data set** and not necessarily the **concept**. If you will try this model on a test set, the performance will be probably be lower indicating the overfit.

However, model capacity is not the only reason that a model cannot represent a concept. It is possible that the concept doesn't belong to the family of functions represented by your model - as when your NN is linear and the concept is not. It is possible that the input is not enough to differ between the samples or that your optimization algorithm simply failed to find the proper solution.

In your case, you have only two predictors. If they were binary it was quite likely you couldn't represent two much with them. 
Assuming that they are bounded and smooth, you can try to bin them.
If you get high entropy in bins (e.g., a bin with 50%-50% distribution), no logic relaying only on these features will be able to differ them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure if I completely understand: I cannot overfit (in the sense of getting an R2 of close to 1) because the models "capacity" is not large enough? Regarding the function the NN is using: I have to specify "linout=T" - does this mean that the NN I'm using is limited to linear functions, and that this might be a reason why the algorithm can't fit better to the training set?

Comment: Usually we try to reach overfitting in order to estimate the needed capacity. That will work if the model can indeed represent the data set, given enough capacity. Since you have a small dataset I believe that capacity is not your problem. What comes to mid is lacking input which you can try to verify using the bins suggested in the answer. Another possible reason are anomalous samples. To which level of performance do you reach on the train set. As for the linear functions, it was a general possibility, not specific to your case. I don't use this library and not familiar with its parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, i kept zero regularisation and optimal learning rate. but the learning rate decay was set to zero. Once I set the learning rate decay to some value like 0.95 it worked and increase the number of epochs

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that somewhere in the neural network you are using dropout? this would prevent overfitting.
Also if there is any regularization (like L2) this would also prevent overfitting.

Comment: Welcome to the site, friend! When asking for clarification, it makes more sense to post as a comment on the OP, rather than as an answer.